# How to parse a string into a datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, raspberry-pi, subtraction

I'm new in the whole programming stuff but I love it.

Currently I am setting up my raspberry pi to show me when my bus is leaving.

I'm getting the information from the local bus company which I then have transformed into a string for example: **'09:15'** (no am/pm).

### **My actual problem:**

I would like python to give me the difference in minutes between now and when the next bus is leaving.

How can I now parse my String to a datetime and then get the difference between now and when the bus is leaving?

```
#m2 is actually from the website and not created by myself

m2 = '09:15'
bustime = datetime.datetime.strptime(m2, '%I:%M')
```

this will actually give me a weird looking date like '1900-01-01 09:15:00'!? And if I then want to subtract 'now' from it there is a huge difference (like 117 years o.O)

Can someone please help me? :-)

### Update

I've got now the date problem but there is still something more:
-> the bustime is given in an 12 hour format but the datetime will create a 24 hour format. How can I solve this but nevertheless calculate the difference after that? As I already mentioned I'd only like to have the minutes as a result!

Comment: There's no date information there. `'09:15'` only has information about time.

Answer (score 0):

You are only supplying hour/min to `strptime`. It's defaulting Y/M/D to 1900/1/1. One way around this would be to create a datetime for today then set the hours minutes to those in the string. The string needs to be split on ':' and converted to integers:

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
hour_min = [int(x) for x in "09:15".split(":")]
bus_time = today.replace(hour=hour_min[0], minute=hour_min[1], second=0, microsecond=0)
print(bus_time)
```

Output:

> 2017-12-21 09:15:00

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a date when constructing the datetime. You could get the time from your input and the date from datetime.now() and combine both.

```
bustime = datetime.datetime.strptime(m2, "%I:%M").time()
todaydate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
bustime = datetime.datetime.combine(todaydate, bustime)
```

Comment: great that one worked very well thanks!
I've got one more problem now - the bustime is given in an 12 hour format but the datetime will create a 24 hour format. How can I solve this but nevertheless calculate the difference after that? As I already mentioned I'd only like to have the minutes as a result!

Comment: If the time is given in a 12-hour-format and there is no am/pm that's ambiguous. Or am i missunderstanding something?

Comment: Well the created 'bustime' is in a 12-hour format but the other variable 'now' (datetime.datetime.now()) is in a 24-hour format. If i now want to subtract them there will be a difference (after 1pm)

Comment: I see that. But you said the bustime is given in a 12-hour-format without am/pm. So how do you know whether your 9:15 is 9:15am (9:15) or 9:15pm (21:15)?  If you don't know that it is ambigous. You could say the time is always the one that's closest to the now time. Is it that what you want?